Next 14 App router - base sitemap 404 not found
Just have a basic app/sitemap.ts defined:
  return [
    {
      url: "https://acme.com",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "yearly",
      priority: 1,
    },
    {
      url: "https://acme.com/about",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "monthly",
      priority: 0.8,
    },
    {
      url: "https://acme.com/blog",
      lastModified: new Date(),
      changeFrequency: "weekly",
      priority: 0.5,
    },
  ];
}

When I do npm run dev - neither of the following URLs are found:
-http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml
-http://localhost:3000/sitemap.xml/0.1
I just get redirected to the not found page.
This is next 14.2.3
